# Joomla, jQuery modules conflicting

Tags: jquery, joomla

I have a custom jQuery accordion menu on my site in a module, when the mod is enabled it breaks my RokSlideshow module.

I can't get them both to work at the same time.

The site is http://www.fbcsheffield.org/2.0

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You have to force MooTools to load first, then load jQuery and tell it to go into No Conflict mode *before* any jQuery code or plugins are executed. Check page 183 of this: http://www.packtpub.com/files/learning-joomla-1-5-extension-development-sample-chapter-8-using-javascript-effects.pdf or this thread on the Joomla forum: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=231&t=283215

Edit: you actually **don't** have to load MooTools first, you just have to make sure that jQuery.noConflict() is called **immediately** after jQuery is loaded: http://www.designvsdevelop.com/jquery-in-joomla-i-was-wrong

Answer (score 1):

use the [jQuery NO CONFLICT MODE](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)

Answer (score 1):

Joomla buffers all content with ob_start(). You can get the current buffer with:

```
$body = JResponse::getBody();
```

You can then find the JQuery and MooTools script declarations and restructure them in a system plugin using the "onAfterRender" event.

You can use preg_replace() to take the JQuery and put in after MooTools. You can then enable the no conflict mode in JQuery.

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
```

Here is an example plugin that changes the MooTools from 1.1 to 1.2. You can do something slimilar for JQuery's no conflict mode.

```
<?php
/**
 * MooTools1.2 w/ 1.1 compat for AjaxChat
 * @copyright www.fijiwebdesign.com
 * @author gabe@fijiwebdesign.com
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
 */

// included only
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Direct Access to this location is not allowed!' );

jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );

/**
 * Joomla PHP Speedy Integration
 *
 * @author gabe@fijiwebdesign.com
 */
class  plgSystemAjaxchat extends JPlugin
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * For php4 compatability we must not use the __constructor as a constructor for plugins
     * because func_get_args ( void ) returns a copy of all passed arguments NOT references.
     * This causes problems with cross-referencing necessary for the observer design pattern.
     *
     * @access  protected
     * @param   object $subject The object to observe
     * @param   array  $config  An array that holds the plugin configuration
     * @since   1.0
     */
    function plgSystemAjaxchat(& $subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);

        $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();
        $document   =& JFactory::getDocument();
        $doctype    = $document->getType();

        // deactivate for backend
        if ($mainframe->isAdmin()) {
            return false;
        }

        // add mootools 1.2
        if ( $doctype == 'html' ) {
            $document->addScript('components/com_ajaxchat/js/mootools-1.2-core.js');
            $document->addScript('components/com_ajaxchat/js/mootools-1.2-more.js');
            $document->addScript('components/com_ajaxchat/js/mootools-1.2-core-compat.js');
            $document->addScript('components/com_ajaxchat/js/mootools-1.2-more-compat.js');
        }

    }

    /**
     * After Templte output is in buffer
     */
    function onAfterRender() {

        $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();
        $document   =& JFactory::getDocument();
        $doctype    = $document->getType();

        // deactivate for backend
        if ($mainframe->isAdmin()) {
            return false;
        }

        // Only render for HTML output
        if ( $doctype !== 'html' ) { 
            return; 
        }

        // get the output buffer
        $body = JResponse::getBody();

        // remove mootools if not needed
        if (stristr($body, 'mootools.js') || stristr($body, 'mootools-uncompressed.js')) {
            $body = preg_replace("/<script.*?mootools(-uncompressed)?\.js.*?<\/script>/i", '', $body);
        } else {
            $body = preg_replace("/<script.*?mootools-1\.2\-.*?\.js.*?<\/script>[\s\t\r\n]*/i", "\n", $body);
        }

        JResponse::setBody($body);
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got moo-tools and jquery conflicting. I'd suggest using a jquery slideshow module - that would be the easiest way.

edit: the conflict looks like they're using the same namespace, but I don't have much time to go in deeper details

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/scripts/7230