# ColdFusion check if jQuery is loaded

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I've created this simple script to check if jQuery is loaded

```
<cfoutput>
<cfif GetPageContext().getCFOutput().getBuffer().findStringNoCase("jquery.js") eq -1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</cfif>

<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("##theValue").val("the replacement");
    });
</script>

<input type="Text" name="theValue" id="theValue" value="the value">
</cfoutput>
```

the whole page is surrounded by `cfoutput`

is there any better solution?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You're not checking whether jQuery is loaded. You're checking for the presence of the string "jquery.js" anywhere in the buffer. On the server. Before the page -- under your control -- is delivered to the browser. This makes no sense.

Comment: @Ken : yes I know that, I'm interesting with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331982/check-if-jquery-is-loaded-in-php/1333085#1333085 checking when the output still at the buffer

Comment: I don't think anything you try like that will be reliable, for any number of reasons -- many of which are outlined in the other answers to the question you linked. The accepted answer, in fact, is a client-side solution that checks for `typeof jQuery`. That's the only way to know with certainty whether or not jQuery is loaded. Plus, wrapping your entire page in `cfoutput` is painful. Every ##cssID or color (##ffffff) has to be double-pounded. Ouch. I'd look hard for a better solution.

Comment: actually I find the whole page cfoutput quite practical, since typically I have anywhere from 10 to 100 variables in a page and wrapping every single use seperately is MUCH harder than remembering to double-pound, ESPECIALLY if you seperate your CSS/JS files externally like you should be anyway.

Comment: I agree with Ken Redler - just use this approach - http://www.coldfusioning.com/index.cfm/2010/7/9/Load-jQuery-From-Google-Without-Risk-of-Breaking-Your-Site 
i.e.

<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') document.write("<scr"+"ipt src='jquery.js'></scr"+"ipt>");
</script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eapen's comment is the best answer.

"I agree with Ken Redler - just use this approach - coldfusioning.com/index.cfm/2010/7/9/… i.e.  if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') document.write(""); " - eapen

Comment: which one is the savest, using document.write or add as <head> child element?

Comment: This is the best way in my opinion: http://www.coldfusioning.com/index.cfm/2010/7/9/Load-jQuery-From-Google-Without-Risk-of-Breaking-Your-Site