# How to prevent Jquery from being loaded several times within a jquery tab

Tags: jquery, struts2

I need your opinion. I'm currently working on a web application, based on struts and Jquery, mainly.

I have the following configuration for one of my pages :

An action with a page containing a JQuery 'tabs' object, pointing **dynamically**, meaning without caching, on several other actions.

Those other actions contain pages with Jquery code too.

My problem is the following, when loading a tab once, and coming back on it, I have some problems because the object that have been associated by selectors are being re-initialised, causing errors.

I tried putting the code at the tabs page level, but since the jquery association is made at the end of the `<body>` loading, I can't get the code to apply to the different tabs...

I'm really lost since I need those tabs to be dynamically loaded as a requirement. Can you tell me if you have any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you move loading jQuery to the `<head>` of your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem : after moving my pieces of code a bit around, I could see that the javascript console was showing me an annoying error, and that I had several versions of the same object, each time I went back on each tab.

error :

> Error: uncaught exception: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

The initialization:

> $('#editbox_0').dialog(...)

was creating a div in the main frame (with all the tabs) every time it was (re)loaded.

But the main thing was related to a single problem : I was using Jquery UI v. 1.8.5, and I found out that there was a bug in this version concerning the method :

> draggable("destroy")

Updating to UI 1.8.9 solved everything... I wasn't wrong, the library was :)

Anyway, thanks everyone.

(Should I close the question, or let it open in case someone has the same problem?)

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a global variable called something like: `alreadyBeenDone` and check if that is 0, if it is then set it to 1. At the end of the function set you can set `alreadyBeenDone` back to 0.

> Show me yours (code) and I will show
>   you mine (code)...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind loading jQuery with javascript, you can do as the answer to this question suggests:
[Check if jQuery is included in Header (Joomla)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331982/check-if-jquery-is-loaded-in-php)

Basically, you do an undefined check on the jQuery object, and if true, then you dynamically load the jQuery libraries.