# jQuery not loading or loading twice

Tags: jquery, joomla

I am working in Joomla and want to add a jQuery script. My index.php looks like this:

```
<script>

    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
    {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/myjqueryscript.js"></script>
```

What I am trying to do is to load jQuery when there is no other jQuery loaded already and do not load it if there already is one.

Answer (score 2):

You should wait until jQuery is loaded on the page before using it. Try this.

```
function ScriptLoaded(){
    alert('jQuery Loaded');
}

if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
   var script= document.createElement('script');
   script.type= 'text/javascript';
   script.onreadystatechange= function () {
       if (this.readyState == 'complete'){ 
           ScriptLoaded();
       }
   }
   script.onload= ScriptLoaded;
   script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RgAg3/1/)**

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't work. How should I wait until jquery is loaded? I have tried so many commands and nothing seems to work but to load jquery directly.

Comment: @user1159265 - Check my edited answer I have fixed it and also added the demo fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RgAg3/.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shankar. It is still not working.
If the other extension is enable (the one that loads it's own jquery) everythink works fine. However if I disable the extension, my script is not working (however I still get the jquery loaded message) only if I load jquery directly <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>.

What should I do?

Comment: You can see in the demo it works fine. I don't understand what you are tring to say.

Comment: HI @user1159265. Your above comment is a bit confusing. From what it sounded to me, the extension you're using seems to be using a different jQuery version than the one you're trying to load manually. Also you told that when your disable the extension, your script is not working. Can you tell us which is the script that is not working.

Comment: I have 2 scripts. One is my script and the other one is a random joomla extension that is calling it's own jqery when enabled. So when both are enabled, both work, but if I disable the random joomla extension (which loads it's own jquery), my script doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind. I have found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329981/joomla-jquery-modules-conflicting/1333301#1333301 Thanks for your help.