# How to fix Mootools and jQuery conflict on Joomla aiContactSafe

Tags: jquery, joomla, mootools

**Overview**

I have a Joomal 2.5 website with [**AiContactSafe**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms/7901) contact form installed. Standard `AiContactSafe` works as a `component` which means, I cannot include a contact form into an article, it has be on its on taking the whole page on my website.

AiContactSafe has a plugin called [AiContactSafeForm](http://www.algisinfo.com/en/tutorials/aicontactsafe/6-aicontactsafeform.html) which enables users to add a form into a page using a tag like `{aicontactsafeform pf=3}`. Number `3` is the id of the form. And what this does is, it enables users to add a form into an article. This plugin uses MooTools.

**Issue**

This works fine as long as I have no jQuery on my page. And when I have jQuery, it clashes with the MooTools library braking my website.

**Question**

How do I fix the jQuery clash. I tried adding `$.noConflict()` to the top of the page after `jQuery.1.8` script but this doesnt fix it. Has any one come across this same issue? Can someone help me to figure this out? Thanks guys.

Comment: This has already been answered several times (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329981/joomla-jquery-modules-conflicting) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810399/jquery-and-mootools-conflict))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the noConflict via this code:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript( '[path to jquery]' );
$noconflict = 'jQuery.noConflict();';
$document->addScriptDeclaration( $noconflict );
```

Comment: I dont have any issues with the component and showing it as a component. The issue is when I try to add the form 'in to' and article using  AiContactSafeForm plugin.

Comment: is there only 1 version of jquery being loaded? or more?

Comment: This is a mootools jquery conflict - see the comment by Sara on the main post