# jquery-script don't work in joomla 2.5 template

Tags: jquery, templates, joomla

I have some problem with jquery on joomla 2.5 template.
Without Joomla, my jquery script( rcarousel) works fine. 
It's my **index.html**, not Joomla! template(connect js-scripts):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="widget/lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="widget/lib/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="widget/lib/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="widget/lib/jquery.ui.rcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="widget/css/rcarousel.css" />
```

And it's script in **scripts.js**:

```
    jQuery(function($) {
    $( "#carousel" ).rcarousel({width: 235, height: 170, visible: 4, step: 4, margin: 5,
    auto: {enabled: true, direction: "next", interval: 5000}, 
    navigation: {prev: "#ui-carousel-prev",next: "#ui-carousel-next" } } );

    $( ".image_slider_right_ex" ).rcarousel({width: 185, height: 160, visible: 5, step: 5, margin: 5,
    auto: {enabled: true, direction: "next", interval: 5000}, orientation: "vertical",
    navigation: {prev: ".slider_right_arrow_down_link",next: ".slider_right_arrow_top_link" } 
    });

    $( "#carousel_laredo" ).rcarousel({width: 320, height: 148, visible: 3, step: 3,
    auto: {enabled: true, direction: "next", interval: 5000},
    navigation: {prev: "#slider_button_left_laredo_link",next: "#slider_button_right_laredo_link" }
    });

    $( ".image_slider_right_laredo_ex" ).rcarousel({width: 210, height: 255, visible: 4, step: 4, margin: 5,
    auto: {enabled: true, direction: "next", interval: 5000}, orientation: "vertical",
    navigation: {prev: ".slider_button_right_laredo_link",next: ".slider_button_left_laredo_link" } 
    });

    $( "#image_gallery_canter_element" ).rcarousel({width: 210, height: 255, visible: 3, step: 1, margin: 2,
    navigation: {prev: "#gallery_button_left",next: "#gallery_button_right"} 
    });
});
```

And it's I connect scripts in Joomla!:

```
 $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
 $doc->addScript($this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template.'/javascript             /scripts.js',   'text/javascript');
 $doc->addScript($this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template.'/javascript/lib/jquery.ui.core.min.js', 'text/javascript');
 $doc->addScript($this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template.'/javascript/lib/jquery.ui.widget.min.js', 'text/javascript');
 $doc->addScript($this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template.'/javascript/jquery.ui.rcarousel.min.js', 'text/javascript');
```

I install easy-jquery plugin. But I have error:

`TypeError: $(...).rcarousel is not a function`

It has identical source code,  that is to say that it's connected jquery scripts. But I've can't understand why it's not work. Help me,please.

Comment: instead of trying to embed a jquery carousel into your template, why don't you look at the JED website and find a [carousel extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=carousel)?

Comment: I've did HTML coding from PSD with sliders, and I want to connect that with Joomla. I'm newbie in Joomla, is it better way to use extension? And still I want to know, what is wrong in this example. I've seen the same problem, but it been the wrong connect mostly

Comment: yes it's far better to use an extension. editing code within a template or any core Joomla file is a bad idea and never recommended. Have a look at the link I provided above and see which one suits your needs ;)

Comment: Check that another instance of jquery isn't being loaded after your script calls. That will usually cause an error like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your problem is caused by jquery-mootools conflict (they both use the $) 
the problem is discussed in the following question: [How to fix Mootools and jQuery conflict on Joomla aiContactSafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040218/how-to-fix-mootools-and-jquery-conflict-on-joomla-aicontactsafe)

Comment: I have easyjquery it's fix this problem. I tried to add code from link into my template, and it's not works